# How to queue a MicroTask to be invoked on the next frame?

Tags: javascript

Running in a modern browser environment not NodeJS:

Is there a way to queue a MicroTask to be invoked in the next frame?

The MicroTask queue gets flushed after a Task, which is before any requestAnimationFrame callbacks.

The MicroTask queue is also flushed again after any rAF callback.

Any rAF callback requested from within a rAF callback does occur on the next frame but only after any Tasks or MicroTasks have been completed.

setTimeout queues a Task but it is not guaranteed to execute on the next frame.

The firing of requestIdleCallback is also unpredictable.

A ResizeOberver sounds like it possibly fires on the next frame though I am not sure but it is only supported in Chrome and polyfills will be rAF or timeout based.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned problems of bare requestIdleCallback and rAF. React has builtin library that claims to solve those problems. Check it out: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/43a137d9c13064b530d95ba51138ec1607de2c99/packages/react-scheduler/src/ReactScheduler.js

Comment: It turns out the ResizeObserver fires same frame after layout but before paint.

Comment: Nubol Thanks for that link, it was very useful.

Looks like the ReactScheduler uses rAF and setTimeout.

They also use PostMessage for an idleCallback which does fire on the next frame, but ti seems to be of a lower priority then setTimeout, as if PostMessage is called from within a rAF and then setTimeout is called the timeout fires first. 

Not sure what happens under load, we know that timers get deferred but no idea if PostMessage does the same.

Comment: I am not too into this problem,  sorry.  If somehow my answer is useful consider upvoting or selecting as best answer